# Getting a duplicate key error in MYSQL. No duplicate found

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table. (Code taken from table generation code, I did not write this)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CatalogueBasket`;
CREATE TABLE  `CatalogueBasket` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Shopper` char(35) NOT NULL default '',
  `ItemLink` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Quantity` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Created` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ExpectedDelivery1` datetime default NULL,
  `ExpectedDelivery2` datetime default NULL,
  `Comments` char(255) default NULL,
  `Status` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `QuantityShipped` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `HarmonyNumber` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `StartDate` datetime default NULL,
  KEY `ID` (`ID`),
  KEY `Shopper` (`Shopper`),
  KEY `ItemLink` (`ItemLink`),
  KEY `Quantity` (`Quantity`),
  KEY `Created` (`Created`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

When trying to insert a new Row at the end of this table I am getting the following message.

```
Duplicate entry '116604' for key 1
```

The insert statement is:

```
INSERT INTO CatalogueBasket (Shopper,ItemLink,Quantity,Created, Status, StartDate) 
VALUES ('0.80916300 1338507348',58825,1,'2012-06-01 09:58:23', 0, '0-0-0')
```

I'm assuming it is talking about the ID column.

If I run the following query I get 116603 as the last key

```
SELECT * FROM `CatalogueBasket` order by ID desc limit 1
```

Any insight / help into this is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an uncommitted transaction lying around? That would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: How could I check to see that?

Comment: can you check the last ID for the auto increment you can do this with phpmyadmin go to the table and check the operation tab with the next auto increment number

Comment: @Jeff Watkings And also what do you mean by Transaction? Are you talking about the "START TRANSACTION" statement?

Comment: @Alsemany auto increment is 116604

Comment: You can check for open transactions by querying the innod engine status iirc. Can't remember the exact syntax.

Comment: Hm, usually, another open transaction hogging that id would just result in 116605 being the next autoincrement assigned. Furthermore: MyISAM does not support transactions.

Comment: I'd say it's time for `ANALYZE TABLE` and possibly `REPAIR TABLE`..